# Invoke Action by reference

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm new to C#, and it looks I need to use `Dictionary<string, Action>`
So I wrote the below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {       
        var functions = new Dictionary<string, Action<string[]>>();
        functions.Add("Foo", CountParameters);
        functions.Add("Bar", SomeOtherMethodName);

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        Action<string[]> action;
        if (functions.TryGetValue("Foo", out action))
        {
            action();
            // What shall I write here to invoke the action!?
        }
        else
        {
            // No function with that name
        }               
    }

    public static void CountParameters(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fn 1");
    }

    public static void SomeOtherMethodName(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fn 2");
    }
}
```

My Question is of 2 parts:

1. How shall I invoke the `Action` if the condition is true.
2. I understood the `Action` is a `Func` with `void` return, but it looks an input `args` is a must, in my case, i do not have an `input args` nor an `output` so is `Action` what I need, or could be something else?

Comment: 1. Call it like you would any method? For example: `action(new string[] { "" });` -- 2. If it is a `Func` it has to have a return type. If it's an `Action` it has no return type. Both can have have as many input parameters as you define (up to 16 I think). That includes *zero* input parameters. Why do you define these Actions/Methods as needing an input parameter `string[]` when they don't actually need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your methods don't don't have return values, an `Action<string[]>` is fine. If they even don't require parameters, you could simply use the non-generic `Action`-delegate and leave out the `string[]`-parameter.

```
var functions = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
functions.Add("Foo", CountParameters);
...
```

Regarding the invocation: The way you've done it in your code snippet is fine if you leave out the (unnecessary) `string[]`-parameter. Just invoke the `Action`-delegate taken from the dictionary like you already did without any parameters: `action();`

Instead of attaching the brackets `()` you could alternatively call `action.Invoke();`.

Comment: I do not know why you added the last edit, actually `Action<string[]> if (functions.TryGetValue("Foo", out action))` did not work and gave me an error at `action` while the previous solution `Action action;
  if (functions.TryGetValue("Foo", out action))` worked perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, this might be a misunderstanding. Simply use an `Action` not an `Action<string[]>`.