# Invoking Action by reference in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I've a Map of (key, value) where the value is a predefined function.
I want to iterate the input param in the Mp and check where the key is matching with the input parameter, then invoke the equivalent function, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446860/invoke-action-by-reference)

My code required to be something like below:

```
fun fn1: Unit {           // using Unit is optional
    println("Hi there!")
}

fun fn2 {        
    println("Hi again!")
}

fun MainFun(x: int){
val map: HashMap<Int, String> = hashMapOf(1 to fn1, 2 to fn2)

for ((key, value) in map) {
     // if key = x then run/invoke the function mapped with x, for example if x = 1 then invoke fn1
}

}
```

Notes: I read something like below, but could not know how to us them:

```
inline fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.filter(
    predicate: (Entry<K, V>) -> Boolean
): Map<K, V> (source)

val russianNames = arrayOf("Maksim", "Artem", "Sophia", "Maria", "Maksim")
val selectedName = russianNames
      .filter { it.startsWith("m", ignoreCase = true) }
      .sortedBy { it.length }
      .firstOrNull()
```

Comment: Why don't you first filter all map entries to leave only those matching your condition and then invoke your function for all remaining entries?

Comment: Why don't you just do `map[x]()`?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What's the difficulty you're facing? Your code is full of syntax errors. Is that the problem?

Comment: @Mibac He need to filter them out first. At least I understood it that way ;)

Comment: @RafalG. As far as I understand he needed to filter them to run only the function he wanted but that doesn't really make sense (e.g. `x = 1` then filter out all the functions that don't return true for the condition `{ key, value -> key == 1}`

Comment: @Mibac you are correct, I want to run only the function I wanted, did not understand `map[x]()` what it is doing can you provide more code lines?

Comment: @JBNizet you are correct, my code if full of errors and that is the problem, not sure what the correct code block shall I use to run only the function I wanted based on the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I hope this would help you.

```
fun fn1() {
    println("Hi there!")
}

fun fn2() {
    println("Hi again!")
}

fun main(args: IntArray){
    val map = hashMapOf(
            1 to ::fn1,
            2 to ::fn2)
    map.filterKeys { it == args[0] }     // filters the map by comparing the first int arg passed and the key
            .map { it.value.invoke() }   // invoke the function that passed the filter.
}
```

If the `key`is `RegEx` then `map.filterKeys { Regex(it).matches(x) }` can be used, below full example of it [Try Kotlin](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/j8i7gd888h8j1p1ippc9tmg7qj/358tljk4jvcni0nj9gsdv12k1j):

```
data class Person(val name: String,
                  val age: Int? = null)

val persons = listOf(Person("Alice"),
                     Person("Bob", age = 23))

fun old() {
    val oldest = persons.maxBy { it.age ?: 0 }
    println("The oldest is: $oldest")
}

fun young() {
    val youngest = persons.minBy { it.age ?: 0 }
    println("The youngest is: $youngest")
}

fun selection(x: String) { 

   val map = mapOf(
            "old|big" to ::old,
            "new|young" to ::young)
    map.filterKeys { Regex(it).matches(x) } 
            .map { it.value.invoke() }   
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {   

    selection("new")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fun fn1() {
    println("Hi there!")
}

fun fn2() {
    println("Hi again!")
}    

fun main(args: Array<Int>){
    val map = hashMapOf(1 to ::fn1, 2 to ::fn2)
    map.forEach { key, function -> function.invoke()  }
}
```

This will do the work but your code does not even have the correct syntax. You should learn the basic first.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua, your solution invoked all the functions in the map, while I need to invoke ONLY the one matched with the input param, so I accepted the other answer.